# splitting the string based on varying spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am reading a text file and I have the following lines in my test file

```
Item1             Item2       Item3   Item4                    Item5      Item6      Item7      Item8                   Item9                  Item10

12345678          TEST       0010  This is a Test              10/12/2016 23:07:24   1066891     TestName                 1232132 

23213213             Test1     0012    This is a Test            10/12/2016   23:07:24  1076578     Testname1                 32432432 

                               0076      This is Test2             10/14/2016   22:10:2  121342       TestName2                  23463246

23213213             Test1     0012    This is a Test            10/12/2016   23:07:24  1076578     Testname1                 32432432           TestQuality
```

I need to parse these lines and put them in the database. The parsing is based on spaces so

tabl1 A

Item1  -> Col1 Item2  ->Col2 Item3->col3 Item4->col4 and so on

My problem is what will the best way to parse the above line because the width/spaces between the items vary and sometimes Item1 and Item2 is not present and only Item3 is present and sometimes Item10 is not present and sometimes Item1 is present and item2 is not present and then rest of the items are present.

If one of the item is not present then I won't insert that particular item in the database and will go on. I know how to insert the items in the database, but I don't know the best way to parse the line with different spaces in between. The good thing is there is always an spaces between the items. Its is just that spaces are not consistent.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't, You must fix your formatting and add a separator between items.

Comment: You are out of luck, that kind of variable content is a hell to parse, if they at least quoted the texts then you would be able to split by the spaces not inside quotes, but without that, you will go crazy before getting something consistent.

Comment: Any more constraints you can deduce? Like "there will never be more than 6 spaces between fields, and never less than 4" or "Item5 will never start later than column 60 or earlier than column 50". Did you list all the cases in your question, or are there other possible cases (like, item2 is present but not item1, etc)

Comment: Also, you call these columns..?  So are they fixed width columns (eg, column 2's data always starts at index 25)?  What is the source of this data?

Comment: You are lucky.  it can be done with the exact data you provided but requires a very custom parser using Regex.  A solution may not work with different data due to the spaces in item 4.  It would be better if the columns where aligned or a delimiter character was used between the columns.

Comment: They are not fixed width columns. The spaces between the columns is uneven.